# Loop through column until blank

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through a panda DataFrame until the columns are blank or does not contain the term 'Stock'. If it contains a date I want the word 'check' to be printed.

I am using:

```
print(df)
    Stock  15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015
0    AA          10          11          11
1    BB          20          10           8
2    CC          30          33          26
3    DD          40          80          60
```

I have tried the below (which is wrong):

```
column = df
    while column != ("") or 'Stock':   
print ('Check'),
column += 1

print ("")
```

Comment: `Stock` is the name of the column rather than a value in the column. Could you please properly explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to loop through the names of the columns - being 'Stock' and the listed dates. If there is a numerical value for a date in the column i want the loop to print 'check'. Then i want the loop to break when the list if dates ends.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems in your code. First of all you've screwed up indentation so it's not even valid code.

Second your comparison is broken because it doesn't mean what you probably expect. `column != ("") or 'Stock'` will always be true because it means that first it will compare `column` with `("")` and if that's equal the expression will be `True`, otherwise it will evaluate `'Stock'` and make that the value of the expression (and in boolean context that would be considered true). What you probably should have written instead is `column != "" and column != "Stock"` or possibly `column not in ("", "Stock")`.

Then I'm not sure if you're looping the right way or using `column` the right way either. Is it correct to step to the next by using `column += 1`? I don't know panda, but it seems odd. Also comparing it to a string may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code really needs improvement. You should follow @skyking advises. I'd like to add that you may want to transpose your dataframe, and put the dates as a variable.

Anyway, let me rephrase what you are looking for, to make sure I got it right: you want to iterate over the columns of your `df` and for every column which name is a date, you do `print('Check')`, otherwise nothing happens. Please, let us know if this is wrong.

To achieve that, here is a possible approach. You can iterate over the columns name and attempt to convert the string to a date, for instance, using [pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime). If successful, it prints a message.

```py
for name in df.columns:
    print(name)  # comment this line after testing
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(name)
    except ValueError:
        pass  # or do something in case the column name is not a date
    else:
        print('Check')
```

This outputs

```
Stock
15/12/2015
Check
15/11/2015
Check
15/10/2015
Check
```

You can see that `Check` was only printed when the column name was, at least, coercible into a date.